# Transforming an ODE with final condition to an ODE with an initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I have an ODE:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}t} + \mathcal{A}(t, u) = 0
$$
with final condition:
$$
u(T)= \mathbf{1}
$$
The function $u:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is vectorial, and the operator $\mathcal{A}$ is locally Lipschitz, but only given implicitly. How can I transform this problem to work with an ODE with an initial condition instead, e.g. I would like to have:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t} + \mathcal{B}(t, v) = 0
$$
with initial condition:
$$
v(0)= \mathbf{1}
$$
What is the relationship between $A$ and $B$, and between $u$ and $v$?

Comment: Set $v(t)=u(T-t)$, then $v'(t)=-u'(T-t)=\mathcal A(T-t,u(T-t))=\mathcal A(T-t,v(t))$.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just shift up the time domain with a transformation like $s=T-t$?